# Does google play console accept 2 apps in ine Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-console

[image]

Google play console cannot enter my app finding Eror 4, although I can enter without problems using Google accounts.

Of course I downloaded the json file correctly before sending to google play console. Here I also leave a pic of the project in my android studio.[image]
So google play is not accepting two apps in one firebase database or am I missing something? I have sent the project many times they always show Error 4.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about app store policies are off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. There in trhe console configuration you can add more apps.